# Jetty cannot start - ContextHandler stopped

Tags: java, jetty, jelastic

I am trying to figure out the root cause while my application would not work when running on Jelastic, while running with maven `jetty:run` locally it works fine.

server.log

> WARNING: System properties and/or JVM args set. Consider using
>   --dry-run or --exec 2016-11-07 18:40:50.290:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1907ms 2016-11-07
>   18:40:50.605:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is
>   not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not
>   recommended. See documentation at
>   http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
>   2016-11-07 18:40:51.001:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property
>   'jetty.host' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.host' instead 2016-11-07
>   18:40:51.001:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'jetty.port' is
>   deprecated, use 'jetty.http.port' instead 2016-11-07
>   18:40:51.489:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.7.v20160115 2016-11-07
>   18:40:51.712:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor
>   [file:///opt/repo/versions/9.3.7/webapps/] at interval 1 2016-11-07
>   18:40:53.903:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@66d2e7d9{/,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-root.war-_-any-7083438667455820054.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/root.war}
>   2016-11-07 18:40:54.002:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@7f6c72a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} 2016-11-07
>   18:40:54.003:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @5619ms 2016-11-08
>   18:53:38.156:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:Thread-1: Stopped
>   ServerConnector@7f6c72a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} 2016-11-08
>   18:53:38.431:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-1: Stopped
>   o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@66d2e7d9{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/root.war} WARNING:
>   System properties and/or JVM args set. Consider using --dry-run or
>   --exec 2016-11-08 18:53:43.393:INFO::main: Logging initialized @1992ms 2016-11-08 18:53:43.599:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance
>   of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this
>   is not recommended. See documentation at
>   http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
>   2016-11-08 18:53:43.983:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property
>   'jetty.host' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.host' instead 2016-11-08
>   18:53:43.984:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'jetty.port' is
>   deprecated, use 'jetty.http.port' instead 2016-11-08
>   18:53:44.400:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.7.v20160115 2016-11-08
>   18:53:44.691:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor
>   [file:///opt/repo/versions/9.3.7/webapps/] at interval 1 WARNING:
>   System properties and/or JVM args set. Consider using --dry-run or
>   --exec 2016-11-08 19:55:19.497:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2182ms 2016-11-08 19:55:19.700:WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance
>   of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this
>   is not recommended. See documentation at
>   http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html
>   2016-11-08 19:55:20.086:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property
>   'jetty.host' is deprecated, use 'jetty.http.host' instead 2016-11-08
>   19:55:20.086:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Property 'jetty.port' is
>   deprecated, use 'jetty.http.port' instead 2016-11-08
>   19:55:20.504:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.7.v20160115 2016-11-08
>   19:55:20.706:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor
>   [file:///opt/repo/versions/9.3.7/webapps/] at interval 1

What could be the main reason why this app on Jetty server would not start?
Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some advice (from the output):

> WARN:oejs.HomeBaseWarning:main: This instance of Jetty is not running from a separate {jetty.base} directory, this is not recommended. See documentation at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup.html

Follow those instructions, setup a proper `${jetty.base}` directory, do not alter, add, delete, rename, or generally change anything in the `${jetty.home}` directory (aka the jetty-distribution directory. `/opt/repo/versions/9.3.7/` on your system)

To start with, unzip (or untar) a fresh copy of the jetty-distribution somewhere on disk.  Then follow the instructions on making a `${jetty.base}` directory (which is the configuration for your specific instance of Jetty, including webapps)